# Docker copy, copies whole root directory instead of subdirectory

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

This is currently how my directory is set up.

```
.
|-src
|--producer
|---Dockerfile
|---requirements.txt
|---main.py
|--consumer
|---*same files as producer*
|-.env
| docker-compose.yml
```

Here's the producer Dockerfile (for consumer just change producer to consumer):

```
FROM python:3.7

COPY requirements.txt /opt/pip/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /opt/pip/requirements.txt

COPY . /app/
WORKDIR /app/src/producer

CMD python main.py
```

Here's my docker-compose setup.

```
version: '3'
services:
    rabbit:
        hostname: rabbit
        image: rabbitmq:3-management
        ports:
            - "5673:15672"
            - "5672:5672"
        env_file:
            - .env
    producer:
        build:
            context: ./src/producer
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        volumes:
            - .:/app
        depends_on:
            - rabbit
        env_file:
            - .env
    consumer:
        build:
            context: ./src/consumer
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        volumes:
            - .:/app
        depends_on:
            - rabbit
        env_file:
            - .env
```

As you can see in the Dockerfile that I had to change the working directory to `/app/src/[producer/consumer]` because whenever I have to run the main.py python script I receive an error that it doesn't exist. According to what I have observed logging into the bash of the specific container of producer or consumer, it seems to copy the root directory instead of the subdirectory/context defined in `docker-compose.yml`.

Any clues on what I did wrong? 
I'm using a a Windows machine if that will lead to anything.
I already did try a the delete everything and build from scratch approach to just make sure no cached containers/commands etc. is the culprit. I even restarted docker desktop to no avail just in case.

Comment: What you expect? Your compose define `.:/app`, so in container it's `/app/src`.

Comment: didn't realize that. thanks! =))